# Как организовать постепенную загрузку данных?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, angularjs

Есть такая задача, в бд хронится огромное количество данных, пользователю с веб страницы нужно с ней постоянно так или иначе работать.
Вообщем нужно порой загружать примерно с 2-4мб информации, а это долго.
Разумеется качать сразу столь большой объем информации мне сразу не нужно, и можно это делать частями. Как правильно это делать?
На данном этапе я при загрузке страницы кидаю ajax(так как сразу эти данные могут и не понадобится), c помощью php вытягиваю из бд огромный ком информации и кидаю обратно.
Может есть типичное решение? Может как то сохранять ответ в кеш, и возвращаться часть инфомации и индекс на тот мамент где остановились...

Comment: Решается пагинацией и постраничной загрузкой.

Comment: С точки зрения пользовательских интерфейсов это может выглядеть как infinite scroll или пронумерованные страницы, или загрузка по ссылке "load more...". Ну а в бэк-энде это всё выливается в использование `SELECT … LIMIT m, n`